# How to create reader & writer samples with xbinder?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, code-generation

According to the [xbinder documentation](https://www.obj-sys.com/support/xbtutorial/XBinderTutorial_17.php), passing `-genreader` and `-genwriter` on the xbinder command line will generate e.g. reader.cpp and writer.cpp . But it's not working for me. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin 444 Jul  6 09:59 cdl.xsd
$ cat cdl.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">


    <xsd:complexType name="cdl">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Polygon" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="Table"   type="xsd:integer" />
        <xsd:element name="Shape"   type="xsd:double" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


</xsd:schema>
$ ~/Downloads/xbv240/bin/xbinder cdl.xsd -c++ -xml -genmake -genwriter


XBinder Compiler, Version 2.4.0 DEVELOPMENT VERSION
Copyright (c) 2002-2016 Objective Systems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Parsing XML schema definitions..
Compiling XML schema file ./cdl.xsd..
Writing C++ type and class definitions to file cdl.h..
Writing C++ encode functions  to file cdlEnc.cpp..
Writing C++ decode functions to file cdlDec.cpp..
Writing C++ common functions to file cdl.cpp..
Generating makefile..

Compilation was successful.
$ ls -l
total 28
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin  878 Jul  6 11:13 cdl.cpp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin 2265 Jul  6 11:13 cdlDec.cpp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin 1402 Jul  6 11:13 cdlEnc.cpp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin 1336 Jul  6 11:13 cdl.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin  444 Jul  6 09:59 cdl.xsd
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin 1220 Jul  6 11:13 makefile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 hrubin hrubin  818 Jul  6 11:13 rtkey.h
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to have a top level element to generate the reader or writer sample programs. Tech support suggested adding this line to the schema file, which worked.

```
<xsd:element name="CDL_ELEMENT" type="cdl"/>
```